# Finding a word in a string in tcl

Tags: string, tcl

I have this string:

> 1, RotD50, 88, 0.1582, 1.2264, -, 7.4, 23.6, 0.2, "San Fernando", 1971, "Santa Felita Dam (Outlet)", 6.61, Reverse, 24.69, 24.87, 389.0, 0.125, 1.2939, RSN88_SFERN_FSD172.AT2, RSN88_SFERN_FSD262.AT2 , RSN88_SFERN_FSD-UP.AT2

I want to find the indices of `RSN88_SFERN_FSD172.AT2` and `RSN88_SFERN_FSD262.AT2`

I have tried a few scripts (like the following) but want to see if someone can help me with a rigorous script?

```
set currentdirc  [pwd]
set  fp  [open  _SearchResults.csv]
set count 1

foreach line [split [read $fp] \n] {
    foreach word [split  $line] {
        set word [string  trim  $word ","]
        set index  [lsearch -exact  $word  "Horizontal-1 Acc.Filename"]
        puts "$index"
    }
}
```

Comment: By 'rigorous', you mean one that actually works or a better one in terms of performance? I can spot a few possible shortcomings from your script, but it's hard to say what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: Hi Jerry !   This code does not actually work as I want. I wanna get the index of "Horizontal-1 Acc.Filename" in the line I introduced at the top. That's all I want from the code !  Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need this:

```
package require csv
```

As before, break the data into lines and iterate over those lines. Trim the data first to avoid empty lines before or after.

```
foreach line [split [string trim [read $fp]] \n] {
```

Instead of trying to split the csv data using the `split` command, use the dedicated command `::csv::split` from the `csv` package in Tcllib. You probably have it in your Tcl installation already.

```
    set words [::csv::split $line]
```

When your line is split, there is unwanted whitespace around many data fields. Let's trim it off.

```
    set words [lmap word $words {string trim $word}]
```

Finally, you can search for data in the list of words. Searching in each word as you did is pointless.

```
    set index [lsearch $words RSN88_SFERN_FSD262.AT2]
```

Putting it together:

```
foreach line [split [string trim [read $fp]] \n] {
    set words [::csv::split $line]
    set words [lmap word $words {string trim $word}]
    set index [lsearch $words RSN88_SFERN_FSD262.AT2]
    puts $index
}
```

Documentation:
[csv (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[read](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the csv package to do that task, since you are dealing with a csv file. Splitting blindly will split `1, RotD50, 88, 0.1582, 1.2264, -, 7.4, 23.6, 0.2, "San Fernando"` things into, for example (each element on their own line):

```
1,
RotD50,
88,
0.1582,
1.2264,
-,
7.4,
23.6,
0.2,
"San
Fernando"
```

So my suggestion is:

```
set currentdirc [pwd]
set fp [open [file join $currentdirc _SearchResults.csv] r]

package require csv
foreach line [split [read $fp] \n] {
    set words [::csv::split $line]
    set index [lsearch -exact $words "Horizontal-1 Acc.Filename"]
    puts $index
}
```

Also the list of words is the whole line. So if you want to loop through the words, you would do `if {$word eq "Horizontal-1 Acc.Filename"}` instead and you would have to use `count` (that I removed in my suggestion) to keep track of the index.

If for some reason you cannot use the csv package, you can try using this instead of the line containing `::csv::split`:

```
set all [regexp -all -inline -- {\"[^\"]+\"|[^,]+} $line]
set words [lmap w $all {set w [string trim $w {\" }]}]
```

(I'm using `\"` for the quotes only for the sake of proper syntax highlighting, you can safely use `"` alone)